# How to get the name and image file from this string?

Tags: php, laravel, react-native

this is the image[0]['uri'] response. How I can get the name and file from this data?

```
file:///data/user/0/com.pardis/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20191226_174428.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also the ever lovely `pathinfo`:

```
$info = pathinfo('file:///data/user/0/com.pardis/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20191226_174428.jpg');

echo $info['basename'];
```

[PHP.net Manual - Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) `pathinfo`

Comment: and how about an array "
`
images: Array(6)
0: {uri: "file:///data/user/0/com.pardis/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20191226_174428.jpg", width: 52.747252747252745, height: 70, mime: "image/jpeg"}
1: {uri: "file:///data/user/0/com.pardis/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20191226_174441.jpg", width: 52.747252747252745, height: 70, mime: "image/jpeg"}
2: {uri: "file:///data/user/0/com.pardis/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20191226_174453.jpg", width: 52.747252747252745, height: 70, mime: "image/jpeg"}

length: 2
`

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode('/', 'file:///data/user/0/com.pardis/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20191226_174428.jpg');
echo array_pop($parts);
```

Yet another option:

```
echo basename('file:///data/user/0/com.pardis/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20191226_174428.jpg');
```

Comment: woked. and I must find a way to get array of images and store the files in images folder uploaded from react-native